# show cpu load in emacs23 status bar

Tags: emacs, cpu-usage, emacs23

I used to have a setting in my .emacs file which enabled the cpu load in my emacs23 status bar. But I don't seem to be able to find the command anymore. 
It used to be on the emacs.wiki but somehow I couldn't find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The system load is shown right beside the time in the status bar. You can display the time when you set the variable `display-time-mode` to `t`.

There are a few options you can set, especially `Display Time Load Average Threshold` (set to 0.1, so load isn't showing up when it is beyond 0.1). You can set these options very easily via `M-x customize-group RET display-time RET`

There are also [some packages](https://blog.idorobots.org/entries/system-monitor-in-emacs-mode-line.html) for further customization.

Comment: Thanksalot xactly  what I was looking for! Unfortunately my reputation is too low to vote you up. Answer is perfect though.

Comment: well, the reputation issue has been resolved. 
I encourage using the cpu-stats.el and memory-stats.el packages - they work like a charm and I don't have to switch terminal or minimize my windows to get to the information conky provided me.
If you use emacs for development these packages are perfect.